# ICS calendar feed with Quarterly recurring events

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

I am working on a ICS calendar feed that will be consumed by different calendar apps. I am using PHP iCal package to generate the feed : https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal

The base system what provides me data for ics feed, has following types of  recurring events:

> Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly

I was looking through RFC doc for this standard https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545, and standard support only following repeat frequencies:

```
   freq        = "SECONDLY" / "MINUTELY" / "HOURLY" / "DAILY"
               / "WEEKLY" / "MONTHLY" / "YEARLY"
```

that means no standard way to have a quarterly recurring event.

One solution that I have in mind is to add a new event after every 3 month. However, this will add 4 separate events in a year, and not 4 recurring instance of original event added.

Is there a way to 'trick' ics to create quarterly 'recurring' events?

Comment: I managed to solve it by setting interval to 3 when creating event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you explore the RFC5545 spec a bit further (next page in the RECUR rule https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-41) , you will find that you can do many things (no 'tricks' needed).  For your example:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=3
```

as demonstrated here: http://test.icalevents.com/event/quarterly-test/.

The INTERVAL rule part contains a positive integer representing at
which intervals the recurrence rule repeats.  The default value is
"1", meaning every second for a SECONDLY rule, every minute for a
MINUTELY rule, every hour for an HOURLY rule, every day for a
DAILY rule, every week for a WEEKLY rule, every month for a
MONTHLY rule, and every year for a YEARLY rule.  For example,
within a DAILY rule, a value of "8" means every eight days.